# st_makepolygon function fails to recognize geo datatypes in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, geospatial

I was trying to create a polygon in snowflake. Got an error saying error parsing Geo input: POLYGON and Did not recognize valid GeoJSON, (E)WKT OR (E)WKB. My question is what should be the input in st_makepolygon function?

Sample data below.

```
create table geo_table (lat1 float, lng1 float, lat2 float, lng2 float, lat3 float, lng3 float);
insert into geo_table values
    (-91.5, 41.6, -82.9, 41,6, -82.9, 42.5);

select 
   st_makepolygon(to_geography('LINESTRING(a,b,c)'))
from 
(select st_makepoint(lat1,lng1) a, st_makepoint(lat2,lng2) b, st_makepoint(lat3,lng3) c
 from geo_table)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending 'LINESTRING(a,b,c)' literal value to the st_makepolygon function. It does not contain any valid coordinates, so it fails.

Another important point is polygon's last point should be the same as the first (i.e. a loop):

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/st_makepolygon.html

As LINESTRING accepts coordinates, you do not need to create points first. So using st_makepoint is not neccessary.

Based on this, here is a working sample:

```
create table geo_table (lat1 float, lng1 float, lat2 float, lng2 float, lat3 float, lng3 float);
insert into geo_table values
    (-91.5, 41.6, -82.9, 41.6, -82.9, 42.5);

select st_makepolygon(to_geography('LINESTRING(' 
          || lat1 || ' ' || lng1 || ','
          || lat2 || ' ' || lng2 || ','
          || lat3 || ' ' || lng3 || ','
          || lat1 || ' ' || lng1 || ' )')) as result
from geo_table;

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                      RESULT                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| { "coordinates": [ [ [ -91.5, 41.6 ], [ -82.9, 41.6 ], [ -82.9, 42.5 ], [ -91.5, 41.6 ] ] ], "type": "Polygon" } |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```